# Loopback 3 model 'belongsTo' many instances of some other model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, loopbackjs

I looked trough all the examples and searched trough the official documentations but I can't find a specific use case.

Ex: You have an 'user' model not assigned to any group. After some groups are created, you can assign existing users to one or more groups. This looks like an embedsMany relationship. What is the method to add user to group and query groups for users?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this -> "HasAndBelongsToMany"
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasAndBelongsToMany-relations.html